# My dataframe i changing when dropping observations conditionaly

Tags: r

I have a df : 262 obs. of 69 variabels

one variabel,
table(data$ex, useNA = "ifany")

0    1     2    3  NA

33    9   25    4  191

I want to drop all obs if data$ex == 0

I tryed different ways

```
        >   data <- data[data2$ex !=0, ]
```

I tryed the subset function

But every time alot of the dataframe changes to NA

How can I drop observation / rows (data$ex == 0) and not change anythin else in the dataframe?

Thanks,
F

Comment: Please, use `dput` to provide a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a very basic use of `subset`.

```r
data |> subset(ex != 0 | is.na(ex))
```

Output:

```r
#>    ex
#> 1   2
#> 2   2
#> 3  NA
#> 4  NA
#> 6   1
#> 8  NA
#> 9   2
#> 10  3
```

PS - create reproducible example

```r
data <- structure(list(ex = c(2, 2, NA, NA, 0, 1, 0, NA, 2, 3)),
                  class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))

data
#>    ex
#> 1   2
#> 2   2
#> 3  NA
#> 4  NA
#> 5   0
#> 6   1
#> 7   0
#> 8  NA
#> 9   2
#> 10  3
```

<sup>Created on 2022-06-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>